# How many points in the finite plane will random lines cover?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Fix a prime power $q$ and a positive integer $n$. On average, what proportion of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ will be covered by randomly drawing $k$ (not necessarily distinct) lines in that space? In other words, if $X_k = |L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \cdots \cup L_k|$, where the $L_i$'s are lines in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ drawn uniformly, what is $E[X_k]$?

For $k = 2$ I believe that the answer is $$E[X_2] = q P(L_1 = L_2) + (2q - 1) P(L_1 \neq L_2).$$ The probability $P(L_1 = L_2)$ is ${q^n \choose 2}^{-2}$, which means this expectation is very close to $2q - 1$. I see how I might evaluate the probability for $k = 3$, but my idea gets foggier as $k$ grows. I can't see any simple recurrences between probabilities here.

As some visual motivation, here's a random drawing of 7 lines in $\mathbb{F}_{17}^2$, where the small, black dots are the uncovered ones:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitrary point in $\mathbb F_q^n$, what is the probability that *one* randomly chosen line falls on the point? It must be $\frac{1}{q^{n-1}}$ on symmetry grounds, since there are $q$ points on every line, and no point is on more lines than any other point does.

Therefore, the probability for an arbitrary point in $\mathbb F_q^n$ to not be hit by any of $k$ randomly chosen lines is
$$ \left(1 - \frac1{q^{n-1}}\right) ^ k $$

And therefore, thanks to additivity of expectations, the expected number of uncovered points is
$$ q^n \cdot \left(1 - \frac1{q^{n-1}}\right) ^ k $$

Comment: Ah, working with the *uncovered* points is significantly easier. Thanks for pointing that out!